# How can I iterate through my firebase nodes in reverse order (bottom - top) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase realtime DB structure is like this:

```
pay_details:--
             |
             |_0
               |_0                                  ^
                 |_Nf230ijw9sdsaju                  |
                 |_N2530asf124d2aj                  |   Iterate like this
                 |_MSFHSJFJs214j12                  |
                 |_UHugqwig28rguhd                  |
```

**My javascript code:**

```
firebase.database().ref("pay_details/0/0/").once('value', function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function (child){
          
        //How do I proceed from here?

    }
}
```

I want to iterate through the nodes in reverse order. How do I do that?

Comment: `snapshot.reverse().forEach(function (child){`

Comment: There's no method called `reverse()` in firebase

Comment: `[...snapshot].reverse().forEach` could work

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Firebase's snapshot to reverse its order, but you can simply get the children in ascending order first and then prepend them to an array:

```
let results = []
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
  results.unshift(child);
});
```

Now you can loop over the array to get the child nodes in descending order

Comment: I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: results.prepend is not a function`

Comment: Oof... thanks for catching that @KonradLinkowski.  I had MDN open to check the method name, and still mistyped it. :)